# Aligning the Bootstrap Form Labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap horizontal form but the problem is label text is not aligned . How can I align the label text.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>

    <head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet"  href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                 <h3>Signup Form</h3><hr/>
                 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Username ..." class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email ..." class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                 </form>

               </div>
             </div>            
          </div>

        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

I want Email label to be aligned with Username label

Comment: they are aligned, on the right... if you want to have it on the left then add `text-align: left;` to the css

Comment: if you want to do by yourself than remove `class` `control-label` and write your `css` for that

Comment: If your issue is resolved, you may accept an answer that helped you, or post your own answer if you solved it in a better way...

Answer (score 1):

It is aligned right by default in Bootstrap stylesheet, you can give your form and id and add something like this to your stylesheet:

```
#signup-form label {
 text-align: left;
}
```

This will align all the labels in your form to left, you may modify the selector to your needs to limit the scope of this style.

Working sample at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lexepo/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this.

**CSS:**

```
.control-label {
  text-align:left!important;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `!important` here